# Issue while connecting to SQL Server 2012 using Perl from Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, perl, odbc

I have installed [`DBD::ODBC`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::ODBC) on a Linux machine, but when I try to connect to SQL Server 2012 it's showing following error

```
DBI connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=<SERVER_NAME>;Database=<DATABASE_NAME>','<USER_NAME>',...) failed: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at script.pl line 47.
```

I am using below code

```
my $dsn = "dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $auth, { RaiseError => 1 });
```

`/etc/odbcinst.ini` file has below entries :

```
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage       = 1

# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

And the `/etc/odbc.ini` file is empty.

Even though I have installed `DBD::ODBC` module there is no entry for SQL Driver. Am I missing something? Why is `/etc/odbc.ini` file empty? Or do I have to enter data into it manually?

Comment: What do you mean by *"there is no entry for SQL Driver"*? Where are you looking for such an entry?

Comment: Get your odbc connection working first, then worry about the Perl side of things. The FreeTDS `tsql` and UnixODBC `isql` tools can help with this.

Comment: @Borodin : I think there should be entry for SQL Server Driver like [PostgreSQL] and [MySQL] in .ini files .....please correct me if I am wrong ....

Comment: Hi, I have installed the unixODBC-2.3.0. But now I am facing new issue, while execution of script - Error : Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so' for module DBD::ODBC: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.

Comment: Code :                                                                         my $dsn = "dbi:ODBC:Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $auth, { RaiseError => 1 });

Comment: Any more configuration changes required?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an ODBC driver for MS SQL Server first. You can get one from Microsoft, Easysoft and other vendors or you could use freeTDS. Once you've installed your driver you need to add entries to /etc/odbcinst.ini like the ones you already have for Postgres and MySQL with a minimum of:

```
[Some_SQL_Server_driver]
Driver = /path/to/shared/object/of/odbc/driver.so
```

The "Setup" keyword identifies another shared object that can be used to provide a GUI setup dialogue to create DSNs but these are rarely available on unix and it only saves you manually creating DSNs in you /etc/odbc.ini file.

You don't need to create DSNs but if you do you use a connection string like 'dbi:ODBC:mydsn' or 'dbi:ODBC:DSN=mydsn' (see ODBC::ODBC for why these differ slightly). If you don't want to create a DSN you can use DSN less connections where you use a connection string like 'dbi:ODBC:DRIVER={Some_SQL_Server_driver};someattr=value;someattr2=value' where "someattr" etc are attributes defined by your driver to tell it how to connect to the database (look these up online).

Likewise, you don't need to even add an entry to /etc/odbcinst.ini as you can use 'dbi:ODBC:DRIVER=/path/to/driver' but that is less common.

If you install a new unixODBC it is possible you need to rebuild DBD::ODBC - it depends how you installed it e.g., via your package manager or built yourself (this one might need a rebuild of DBD::ODBC as you'll have new header files that DBD::ODBC uses from unixODBC). If you use unixODBC packages and still want to rebuild DBD::ODBC you will need to make sure you install the unixodbc-dev package as well as unixodbc.

Your new issue with unixODBC is, I believe down to the fact that the version changed to 2 at some time and the symbolic links created are sometimes wrong. Look in /usr/lib and below for files called libodbc* and check the symbolic links point to an existing .so file.

Of course, as you appear to be using a 64 bit Perl, you'll need a 64 bit unixODBC and ODBC driver - they all have to match.

Best of luck.

UPDATE: I omitted the reason for having to rebuild DBD::ODBC. If you have a version 1 unixODBC but built 64bit an SQLLEN type is 32 bits. If you build against this and then upgrade to version 2 unixODBC, an SQLLEN type changes to 64 bits. If you don't rebuild DBD::ODBC you'll likely get all sorts of problems like seg faults and access violations.